# Interface method that receives a parameter of type of class that inherited it

Tags: c#, class, methods, interface

I' trying to make something like this:

```
public interface ICar
{
    public void Update(/*something here*/);
}
```

Then two classes:

```
public class Peugeot : ICar
{
    public void Update(Peugeot car)
    {

    }
}

public class Volvo : ICar
{
    public void Update(Volvo car)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The OP probably wants to restrict each implementation to only accept its own type, although he forgot to mention it.

Comment: What would the Update method do with its parameter?

Comment: As @boli asked, what's the point in doing this? How does the `car` parameter differ from the actual instance processing it (the `this` instance, if you will)?

Answer (score 2):

You could make `ICar` generic:

```
public interface ICar<T> where T : ICar<T>
{
    public void Update<T>(T car);
}
```

And then implement the `Update` methods accordingly:

```
public class Peugeot : ICar<Peugeot>
{
    public void Update(Peugeot car)
    {

    }
}

public class Volvo : ICar<Volvo>
{
    public void Update(Volvo car)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this (usually known as a [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) doesn't prevent you from writing `class Plane : ICar<Volvo>`. Eric Lippert also mentions the issue [in his article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can (at least sort of) achieve this by making an explicit interface implementation, and then providing a public `Update` method that is properly typed:

```cs
public interface ICar
{
    void Update(ICar car);
}

public class Peugeot : ICar
{
    public void Update(Peugeot car)
    {
        Update(car);
    }

    void ICar.Update(ICar car)
    {
        // do some updating
    }
}

public class Volvo : ICar
{
    public void Update(Volvo car)
    {
        Update(car);
    }

    void ICar.Update(ICar car)
    {
        // do some updating
    }
}
```

Comment: If `ICar.Update` is going to do all the work on a common interface, I don't see the point in having a separate method specific to that derived type.

Comment: @Groo It would prevent you from writing code like `new Volvo().Update(new Peugeot());` which would be allowed with only the regular interface implementation. You can still write `((ICar)new Volvo()).Update(new Peugeot());` but it's harder to get it wrong that way.