# Using type in generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics

I'm studying with C# in depth book and it mentions that a form of constraint uses the type parameter in the constraint itself. So what is the difference between these two:

```
public void Method(AClass<T> myobject) where T : ISomething //Here I say that T has to implement ISomething

public void Method(AClass<T> myobject) where T : ISomething<T> //I don't understand this
```

Comment: Probably what *you* are asking is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186347/interface-method-that-receives-a-parameter-of-type-of-class-that-inherited-it... But the question itself is quite unclear... so not yet closing as duplciate.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that you have a non-generic interface `ISomething` defined. The first line constrains `T` to types that implement that interface.

Now consider that you have a different, generic interface `ISomething<T>` defined. The second line says that T is constrained to types that implement that interface, but with the further restriction that the generic parameter on the interface must the set to the type that you are specifying.

For example

```
interface ISomething<T> { /* methods */}

class MyClass: ISomething<MyClass> { /* methods */ }
```

See the relationship that `MyClass` has with `ISomething<T>`. That's what that constraint is demanding.

C++ programmers call this the *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Don't worry it tends to melt everyone's mind the first time they encounter it. And, if you don't use it for a while, it's not like riding a bike; you need to learn it all over again

Comment: I spent these days reading the few resources I found regarding CRTP with C# and I think the second line means not that T implements the interface, but that the interface can be applied on T, that is, T fulfills the internal restrictions of the interface. What do you think?